# How to translate "milkshake" in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

This word is absent in all the dictionaries I use. Is there a common way to refer to a milkshake, or how to construct a word that would be understood?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In [Sonja's English-Esperanto Dictionary](http://esperantodictionary.org/index.php?letter=m):

> **milkshake** N laktoskuaĵo <sup>PB</sup>, laktokirlaĵo <sup>ANZ</sup>, mikstrinkaĵo el lakto, glaciaĵo kaj gustigaĵo

Abbreviations:

- **N** Noun
- **PB** Complete English-Esperanto Dictionary, by Peter Benson
- **ANZ** [Australian and New Zealand Esperanto Dictionary](http://en.esperanto.org.nz/dictionaries/australian-new-zealand-to-esperanto/m), by Ralph Harry and Brian Fox